# auth()->user() returns null in Laravel 9, Passport Api middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-9

I'm using Passport package for authentation and the auth is working fine in routes and controllers.

I want to make a custom middleware for Admin chekcing, But auth()->user() returns null.

This is my middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->is_admin == 1){
        return $next($request);
    }
    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Allowed'], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}
```

and this is my Karnel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminCheck::class,
];
```

Comment: Are you sure you are currently logged in?

Comment: yes, and by the way I'm using Passport auth package @aceraven777

Comment: So you're using API right?

Comment: Kindly edit your question and include that you're using Passport auth package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Auth::user()`, it will use the default guard in your `config/auth.php`, which I think currently its `web`. You can change the default to `api` if you want:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

OR alternatively you can `Auth::guard` to use a specific guard. e.g. `Auth::guard('api')->user()`. Documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#accessing-specific-guard-instances

So your middleware will look like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::guard('api')->user() && Auth::guard('api')->user()->is_admin == 1){
        return $next($request);
    }
    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Allowed'], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aceraven777, Auth::guard('api')->user(); solved my problem. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of using Auth::guard('api') everywhere use api middleware directly on the routes in api.php or web.php.

you can do like this:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['api', 'othermiddleware']], function () {
  
 //put your route here.

});

// for auth route

  Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'othermiddleware']], function () {
  
 //put your route which require auth checking.

});
```